# How @Service class is exposing and intercept methods on top of Repository

Tags: spring, service, spring-boot

My question is in Spring Boot. I have created domain class, `CRUD repository` class and `@Service` wired service class. I have written some methods in `@Service` class like save entity based on some conditions and code is working fine.

My question is, how `spring boot` invokes particular method when I call `REST POST` method?

Comment: Do you use spring-data-rest?

Comment: Please provide some code. From your description it's very hard to get what you have and what you want.